# Nginx rewrite with + and ;

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have problem with rewrite:

```
location = /special+character {rewrite ^/special+character https://www.mysite.us permanent;}

location = /special;character {rewrite ^/special;character https://www.mysite.us permanent;}
```

If I use + or ; in url, it doesn't redirect to my URL. Also, i tried url encode, but the problem is same.

Comment: Use the quotes, Luke

Comment: Also, you will need to escape the `+` when it is in a regular expression.